# TRIGGER_PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE: This request would cause a function payload exceeding the maximum size allowed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase function which is writing data to firebase realtime database, but it crashes with error  TRIGGER_PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE: This request would cause a function payload exceeding the maximum size allowed.
Where there are alot of push notifications under a userid node, then the function crashes, with less number of push notifications under userid, the function runs well

```
var arr = bedId.split(/\s+/);
                        var r = admin.database().ref("UserNotifications/" + userId).push();
                        var pushkey = r.key;
                        var ref = admin.database().ref("UserNotifications/" + userId);
                        if (posValue == 0 && sentValue == 0 && sentXValue == 0 && sentUITValue == 0) {
                        } else {
                            //var childRef = ref;
                            return ref.child(pushkey).set
                            (
                            {
                                pos: posVal,
                                sent: sentVal,
                                sentx: sentXVal,
                                sentuit: sentUITVal,
                                time: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                                datetime: moment.tz(Date.now(), "Europe/Amsterdam").format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss"),
                                institute: arr[0],
                                bed: arr[1],
                                posnum: "" + posValue,
                                sentnum: "" + sentValue,
                                sentxnum: "" + sentXValue,
                                sentuitnum: "" + sentUITValue,
                                dnl: "" + dnlValue,
                                dnr: "" + dnrValue,
                                upl: "" + uplValue,
                                upr: "" + uprValue
                            }
                            );
                        

                        }
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that you're trying to write too much data at once.  We can't measure that for you given all the variables we can't see here, so you're going to figure out how to reduce this yourself.

Comment: Its not about writing too much data.  ref.child(pushkey) is getting all the notifications i have under the userId, With less number of notifications under userId node, the function runs well. It crashes when there are alot of notifications under the userId